# Plain history.pushState or replaceState functions doesn't work in vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-history

I use `history.replaceState` or `history.pushState` in my own project which written by vue.js, why they don't work.
Actually, I can saw the url address has changed in address-bar: from 'location:3030/#/a' to 'location:3030/#/b', but sadly current page doesn't change.

```
history.pushState({key: 641.928}, '', 'http://localhost:3030/#/a');
```

I expect that page `a` would jump to new page `b`;

Answer (score 2):

`history.pushState` will not modify the page, only the url. If you want to navigate to a new page and reload you can use `window.location.href="http://localhost:3030/#/a"`. This will reload the page.

If you do not want to reload the page you must first change the page content manually (vue makes this easy), and then call `history.pushState` to change the URL.

Answer (score 1):

history.pushState only updates the history. you have to listen to history changes (user goes backwards or forwards) with the [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event).

```
// update the history
history.pushState({key: 641.928}, '', 'http://localhost:3030/#/a');

// user clicks the back or forward button
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
   myFunction(event.state.key);
});
```

this video describes how to achieve what you are looking for pretty well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRC0hOh4UGY